# How can i filter html output in python?

Tags: python, html, filter, beautifulsoup

I need help to filter html output,
here the output:

`button /div div class="b-header_actions-item m-account" div id="csrf-token-element" data-token-name="csrf_token" data-token-value="WHAT I WANT"`

Is it possible to filter this out?

Thanks

Comment: What output specifically do you want to get?

Comment: just after data-token-value="THIS" not more

Comment: so you want to get the value of the attribute `data-token-name` which is `"csrf_token"`? And can you please show us the HTML tag itself. It looks like that you included the XPath

Comment: wait here is a screenshot:
https://imgur.com/a/Kfdpobv

yes i want the value from data-token-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYXsJ.jpg) in the comment, you can get the attribute value with the following snippet:

```py
html_doc = '<div id="csrf-token-element" data-token-name="csrf_token" data-token-value="WHAT I WANT"></div>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")
tag = soup.find(id="csrf-token-element")
tag.attrs["data-token-value"]
```